# Sails ignoring CORS settings

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I've been trying to set up CORS in Sails 0.12.0 on a per route basis. According to the documentation, it should only be a matter of adding a "cors" object to the routes where you want to override the global settings. I did it like this:

**routes.js**

```
module.exports.routes = {

  '/': {
    view: 'homepage'
  },

  'GET /widget/render/:id': {
    controller: 'WidgetController',
    action: 'render',
    cors: {
      origin: '*',
      credentials: false
    }
  }
};
```

I'm not sure if the headers should be added inside the controller, or if it's enough to use the route configuration, but I'm only getting empty CORS headers in every request.

Comment: I think you **also** need to set up [sails.config.cors](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-cors)

Comment: But the docs say "Note that these settings (with the exception of allRoutes) can be changed on a per-route basis in the config/routes.js file".

Comment: Yeah, I read that, but [this](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/security/cors#/enabling-cors) suggests how to enable, and the other paragraphs below that is how to **configure** cors .. you say you do actually get cors headers, they're empty though?

Comment: The setting you are referring to, is one that tells sails to enable CORS globally, which means every request would be allowed for any route (if I understood correctly). Yep, I get the headers, but all of them are empty.

Comment: How are you actually making the request?  If you're not actually making a cross-origin request (e.g. an AJAX request from a different domain), then the headers will be empty.  On a fresh Sails app with your route config and a simple `render` action that just does `res.send("OK");`,  I was able to go to http://code.jquery.com and do `$.get("http://localhost:1337/widget/render/123")` successfully.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I got confused by the behavior and our setup didn't make things easier. Thank you very much, and thanks for taking the time to answer to the issue at github.